# Getting error while adding ubuntu/trusty64 Vagrant Box

Tags: vagrant

Command: `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64`

output:

```
The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error: error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied
```

what needs to be done to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fetching this image from office network. Probably due to secured environment, i got that error. When i did the same from my home wifi, it happened with out any errors.

It may not sound technical, but this is how i resolved it.